# alfresco Upgrading module

Tags: upgrade, alfresco

We are trying to upgrade module package version through jar currently we have myjar-cms-alfresco-3.1.60.jar and we are trying to upgrade it by replacing the jar file in webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/lib and replacing the old jar with myjar-cms-alfresco-3.1.61.jar. We are facing an error where tomcat is still look for myjar-cms-alfresco-3.1.60.jar instead of our replaced jar file i.e cms-alfresco-3.1.61.jar, also after changing the name of my new jar to myjar-cms-alfresco-3.1.60.jar
to fix the issue.
We are getting error Module 'MyModule-cms' version 3.1.60 is currently installed and must be uninstalled before version 3.1.61 can be installed.

Suggest Us how we can uninstall the module and upgrade it to newer version, we have cross verified that new jar works
in our local enviroment.

We are trying to upgrade module package version through jar currently we have myjar-cms-alfresco-3.1.60.jar and we are trying to upgrade it by replacing the jar file in webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/lib and replacing the old jar with myjar-cms-alfresco-3.1.61.jar. We are facing an error where tomcat is still look for myjar-cms-alfresco-3.1.60.jar instead of our replaced jar file i.e cms-alfresco-3.1.61.jar, also after changing the name of my new jar to myjar-cms-alfresco-3.1.60.jar
to fix the issue.
We are getting error Module 'MyModule-cms' version 3.1.60 is currently installed and must be uninstalled before version 3.1.61 can be installed.

we were expecting it to be upgraded to our version.

Comment: What is your version of Alfresco and type of installation? Changing directly jars in tomcat is not prefer way how to custom Alfresco. You should use Alfresco SDK project and change your library in it.